# Copy UDP packets to another destination

Tags: udp

I have application A sending UDP packets to application B on port 10002.
They both run on the same PC and communicate through the local IP 127.0.01

What I need is a way to copy UDP packets and send them also to application C (also running locally) ; so that UDP packets go to both applications B and C.

Applications A is ready made application, I do not have its source code otherwise I would update it to send UDP packets to multiple destinations.

Operating system is Windows 8

I searched a lot and could not find a software to do that.
Should I write my own code for this ? To snif for the UDP packets I am interested in, take copy and send them to application C.

Thanks

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: You have to include more details. Frankly, an attempt at doing this yourself would be the best.

Comment: Operations system is Windows 8